# How to push value in List of Object?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

A problem occurred while the Java project was in progress, so I asked a question.

For example, suppose we have this Object in JavaScript.

```
let testObject = {
   'Fruit' : [],
   'Food': []
}
```

I can add a value to the food array.

```
testObject['Fruit'].push('tomato');
testObject['Food'].unshift('ramen');
```

Like javascript, java directly pushes a value to a list of objects.

```
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> testObject = new HashMap<>();
        testObject.put("Food",new ArrayList<>());
        testObject.put("Fruit",new ArrayList<>());
        for(T etc : testObject...){
            if(etc...equals("Fruit")){
                etc..add('tomato');
            }else if(etc..equals("Food")){
                etc..add('ramen');
            }
        }
```

Is there any way other than to declare ArrayList in advance using call by reference and put it in testObject?

Comment: Even in JavaScript, you're creating the array beforehand (using `[]`), so that's no different. But you can use `testObject.computeIfAbsent` if you don't want those `.put()` calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of java 8+ you can try something like this:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> food = new HashMap<>();

// ... any code ...

food.computeIfAbsent("fruits", k -> new ArrayList<String>()).add("apple");
```

Answer (score 4):

### Assuming key is present in map

`testObject.get("Fruit").add("tomato")`

### Assuming key may not be present in map

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> testObject = new HashMap<>();
        testObject.put("A", new ArrayList<>());
        testObject.get("A").add("tomato");
        testObject.computeIfAbsent("B", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add("tomato");
        System.out.println(testObject);
    }
```